# How can I use Javascript to “click” a button that has no ID?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I'm trying to click a button without ID. Already tried document.querySelectorAll and document.getElementsByClassName with no success.

The button code:

```
<input name="1X" type="2X" class="3X" style="width:160px;" value="4X" data-role="5X" role="5X" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: Yes, you can address any element in the DOM, you don't need an ID. It's impossible to say *how* if you don't show what the HTML looks like, though.

Comment: Also, what was the problem with `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: Could do `document.getElementsByName('1X')[0]` I guess. Assuming there aren't any other elements with the same name before the one you're trying to select.

Comment: That might be a contrived example, but that input element is not actually a button. `type="2X"` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element in the document can be selected using CSS selector syntax via:

- `document.querySelector('css selector')` (returns the first matching element)
- `document.querySelectorAll('css selector')` (returns all matching elements).

To actually *click* the button, just call `click()` on the element, like so:

```
var button1X = document.querySelector('input[name="1X"]');
button1X.click();
```

For more details on querySelector/All: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

You can use element name:
`document.getElementsByName( '1X' )[0]` or `document.querySelector( '[name="1X"]' )`
Or any attribute:
`document.querySelector( '[data-role="5X"]' )`

`getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`, not single element. You can get access to single element in array-style:
`document.getElementsByClassName( '3X' )[0]`
The same thing is with `getElementsByName`

And make sure that your attribute values (class, name, etc.) **begin with a letter, not a digit**

Comment: Why are you saying that attribute values need to begin with a letter? Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Not me, HTML specification says that. You can find naming rules here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

Comment: Something didn't sound right about this, so after a bit of googling, it looks like this constraint only applies when using a class as a CSS selector: https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: *CSS specification says that. I think it's good practise to follow CSS specification.

Comment: Sure. However, the css specification is only referring to class names, not all html attributes (which is what the answer currently implies). In modern html, it is perfectly acceptable to set any attribute (aside from `class`) to a value that begins with a non-letter (even an ID). As written, the answer is misleading.